# Outputting XMLSerializer().serializeToString String to User Savable Text Window

Tags: javascript, xml-serialization

I am currently using the following code to display the XML code from part of the DOM.

```
var sXML = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.getElementsByTagName("TopElementOfBlockOfInterest")[0]);
var win;
var doc;
win = window.open("", "", "",false);
doc = win.document;
doc.open("text/plain");
doc.write(sXML);
doc.close();
```

What I see is XML code.  However, when I choose "Save As" on Firefox 20.0, what is saved is an html file.  Is there a way to display the XML string in a form in which the user save save the XML code to a file?  The way it is now, the user can copy and paste but I would prefer a more conventional Save operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert it to a data uri and then open that

```
var uri = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString( // serialise
        document.getElementsByTagName("TopElementOfBlockOfInterest")[0]
    ),
    win;
uri = 'data:text/plain,' + window.encodeURIComponent(uri); // to data URI
win = window.open(uri, '_blank'); // open new window
```

*SaveAs* will now default to `.txt`. You may also wish to use *MIME* `text/xml` or `application/xml` as you're actually displaying *XML* content, however this might be rendered rather than displayed as plain text, when viewed in a browser.